# Модульные стили. Связь классов в разных компонентах

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, scss

Есть проект на React.js в котором используются модульные стили.
Структура для этого примера:

[image: text]

разметка в `column.js`:

```
<div className={styles.column}>
    <Item/>
</div>
```

и стили для него в `styles.module.scss`:

```
.column{
    width: 200px;
}
```

разметка в `item.js`:

```
<div className={styles.item}>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" alt="">
    <span>Name</span>
</div>
```

и стили для него в `styles.module.scss`:

```
.item img{
    display: none;
}
```

на выходе получается такая разметка:

```
<div class="ajcv_column__xcvk">
    <div class="cvbn_item__vbnv">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" alt="">
        <span>Name</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

каким образом можно сделать, чтобы при наведении на `.column` `.img` внутри item`a принимал значение block?

в обычной ситуации я бы написал

```
.column:hover .item img{
    display: block;
}
```

но как это сделать с модульными стилями?

Comment: А почему вам не использовать для этого react? `<div>{ifOtherComponentHovered && <p>На другой компонент навели, я должен рендериться</p>}</div>` На контролирующий компонент вешаете `onHover={() => setIfOtherComponentHovered(true) }` (если не поддерживает hover событие, тогда события наведения мыши)

Comment: Пример: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cartwright-bdgur?file=/src/App.js я понимаю, что мое решение не решает вопрос с css модулями, но все же предложенное решение может обезопасить вас от кучи проблем с css.

Comment: @Александр в данном случае не подходит, потому что изначально картинка видна, а потом, на меньших экранах, она скрывается и нужно чтобы она появлялась при наведении на родитель

Comment: Поменять начальное состояние на `true` тоже не решит вашу проблему?